# Debug Protractor tests using Nodeclipse

Tags: protractor, nodeclipse

I am using **Nodeclipse** to create a test automation framework using **Protractor**. However, I'm not able to debug (step through my code). I am however able to successfully do so using **WebStorm**. Its really very frustrating to debug tests using Protractor's ***browser.pause();*** and ***browser.debugger();*** statements.

Can anyone please help on this ? Is there any particular configuration which needs to be done on Nodeclipse just as we do on WebStorm as shown here: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/debugging.md

Comment: I have now solved this by using Microsoft Visual Studio Code.